# call jquery alert function or methods in MVC4 controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i want to call a jquery alert box in the mvc 4 controller but how to i do that?

heres my jquery code in my razor.cshtml

```
    $( function errMsgBox()
    {
        alert( "Please select the Correct Activity and Task" );
        window.location = "/Memory/Create";
    } );
```

heres my controller codes

```
 catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                return View("Create");
            ~~here is i want to call the jquery method~~
```

}

Comment: You can't call JavaScript inside a controller action. You can have the view include a call to that JavaScript function though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Javascript within the controller. If you want to pass the error message into the page, then you have to use the `ViewBag` or a return model.

Here's a quick `ViewBag` example:
In the controller

```
protected ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";

    //some code
    try
    {
        //more code
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "alertError('" + ex.Message + "');";
    }

    return View();
}
```

In a Razor view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertError(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        //some code
    }
    @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
</script>
```

Similar to what @NewAmbition suggested, to call it after the page completes loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertError(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        //some code
    }

    $(function() {
        @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you may want to update your code to put `var error = '@ViewBag.ErrorMessage'` inside a `$(document).ready({` function, then  `if(error.length > 0) { alert(error); }` - Just an idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the controller:

```
catch (Exception ex2)
{
ViewBag.ErrorMsg = "Any string you want";
     return View("Create");
}
```

Then in View "Create":

```
@if(ViewBag.ErrorMsg == "Any string you want")
{
<script type="text/javascript">
alert( "Please select the Correct Activity and Task" );
</script>
}
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this, if is ok javascript too.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
   var script = "alert('Message from Server');";
   return JavaScript(script);
}
```